# Condition in where clause with codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

My table structure is

```
CREATE TABLE `emp_bank` (
  `bank_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `emp_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bank_name` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'pk from emp_bank_name tb',
  `branch_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ac_num` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ac_holdername` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ac_type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `routing_num` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `pay_mode` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ac_active` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '1=personal ac, 2=salary ac'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I want to select all data from this table. My condition is, select all data where type=2 if type=2 not exist then select all data where type=1

Table data:

```
 INSERT INTO `emp_bank` (`bank_id`, `emp_id`, `bank_name`, `branch_name`, `ac_num`, `ac_holdername`, `ac_type`, `routing_num`, `pay_mode`, `ac_active`, `type`) VALUES
(21, 32, 8, 'Statue', '3301000400020423', 'Adarsh', 'Salary Savings', 'PUNB00023', 'Online', '1', 1),
(32, 66, 16, 'er', '43243', 'd3f', 'Salary Savings', '34', '34', '1', 1),
(33, 66, 23, 'fewr', '234', 'def', 'Current', 'er4', 'fdf', '1', 2),
(34, 68, 24, 'wer', '12323', 'erer', 'Savings', '4234', 'wer', '1', 1),
(35, 68, 25, 'wer', 'w434', 'ewr34', 'Savings', 'er', 'rwer', '1', 2),
(38, 75, 27, 'hn', '1234', 'dd', 'Savings', 'dd3', 'dd', '1', 1),
(39, 75, 8, 'ktm', '123', 'dd', 'Salary Savings', 'dd2', 'dd', '1', 2);
```

Comment: Clarify `if type=2 not exist then select all data where type=1`.

Comment: Pls also share what you have tried so far to achieve the desired output!

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen correct

Comment: I want data with bank id 21,33,35,39

Comment: This doesn't agree with the logic you gave us in your original question.  Please update the logic to match what you are really asking us for.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
// get type 2 data
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM emp_bank WHERE type = 2");
$result = $query->result_array();
$count = count($result); // get count

if (!empty($count)) {
    // Type 2 have data
    return $result;
}
else{
    // Type 2 dont have any data. So getting data from Type 1
    $query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM emp_bank WHERE type = 2");
    $result1 = $query->result_array();
    return $result1;
}
```

Comment: @AdarshMPallickal any response ??

Answer (score 0):

Here is a single query which will generate your result set:

```
SELECT *
FROM emp_bank
WHERE ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM emp_bank WHERE type = 2) > 0 AND type = 2) OR
    ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM emp_bank WHERE type = 2) = 0 AND type = 1)
```

And here is the PHP code:

```
$where_clause = "((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM emp_bank WHERE type = 2) > 0 AND type = 2)";
$where_clause .= " OR ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM emp_bank WHERE type = 2) = 0 AND type = 1)";

$this->db->select("*)
->from("emp_bank")
->where($where_clause);
```

Comment: in this case data displayed only when there is type 1 and 2 exist

Comment: No.  Data will be shown only if type 1 _or_ type 2 exists.  This is your original requirement.

Comment: this query failed when only one entry. if two entry working fine

Comment: What do you mean by "one entry?"

Comment: in table there is lots of entry. one employee have two entry. ie type 1 and type 2. Some employee have only one type either 1 or 2. Your query display only the data of employee who have multiple entry

Comment: Show us sample input and output.  I believe my current query answers your question.

Comment: Now in my question include data. Your query list only bank id 33,35,39

Comment: You never showed us the output you want.  Please include this as well.

Comment: sorry @Tim Biegeleisen